# Bridging Swift and Objective-C not working completely

Tags: objective-c, swift, header, xcode8

I just migrated a big project from Xcode 7 to Xcode 8 and after solving a lot of issues I realized I have no autocompletion or class detection of the Swift classes I have on the Objective C View Controllers but when I compile everything works perfectly. I can see that the umbrella header [My-Project]-Swift.h is being generated in DerivedData so that's why the compile process doesn't fail but I find pretty rough to work without autocompletion.

Is there any build setting I might be missing?

Comment: We'd need a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because auto-complete works for me. A couple of questions: 1. You definitely did the `#import "Project-Swift.h" and autocomplete still isn't working? 2. What version of Xcode are you using? 3. Is your Swift code Swift 2.3 or 3? Regardless, I'd quit Xcode, empty the derived data folder and restart Xcode (or even reboot) and see if the problem persists. Sometimes weirdness like this is just an artifact of messed up derived data folder. If that doesn't do it, outline the steps necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: 1. I did, is under my pch. 2. Xcode 8, 3.Swift 3.... I already did all you mentioned.

Comment: If it's a very large project, the "Indexing..." stage can take a while. Start up Xcode and wait 2-3 minutes. Do you see that process starting?

Comment: The indexing already finished, I am having this issue since yesterday

Comment: This is a silly question, but you're doing a build before you try to use auto-completion, right? If you "clean" the project, you'll lose the `XXX-Swift.h` file and thus auto-completion. But if you build, you should re-gain auto-completion.

Comment: @DavidVelardeRobles Take new .h file and in build settings -> prefix header -> Give path of that file . Here in this .h file you can import all objective c files and working in swift successfully. This can solve your problem. If you want screenshots then i will post my answer

Comment: @Rob yes, I do that but with no luck.

Comment: @Jecky just tested that, no luck so far

Comment: @DavidVelardeRobles - OK, so we now need to determine whether its your project or your computer. Here's a sample project which does enjoy code completion of Swift method called from Objective-C: https://github.com/robertmryan/SampleBridgingProject. See if code completion works. If so, you can start to examine your project for differences (or, like I suggested earlier, create your own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). If not, then it's something about your computer's configuration.

Comment: @DavidVelardeRobles If you want screenshots then I will post it within my answer ?

Comment: Having the same issue. `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FadingEdgesCollectionView* cvToolMenu;` - `FadingEdgesCollectionView` is a `UICollectionView` subclass written in Swift - trying to use in ObjectiveC gets me this: http://goloskok.com/u/image-2Jtl1jyqmc.png  Detects fine in Xcode 7.3.1. Tried cleaning derived files, build folder, rebuilding etc no luck

Comment: While trying to fix this tried changing `SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME` to default value (from a hardcoded one that was set to be shared between diff targets). After cleaning derived files folder it started working, but then even after changing back and cleaning derived it still works :/

Comment: @AlexandreG you were absolutely right, apparently this is an error for whom have multiple targets and a single Interface Header Name, I tried your solution and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who is facing this same issue, the solution for this bug is changing the SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME value and then return it as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your xCode project to fix code autocomplete.

I recently experienced this issue in my swift code after I added a swift file in my originally objective c project. When I experience issues like this, the first thing I usually do is restart the project.